# SQLAlchemy reflected classes in separate files

Tags: python, class, reflection, sqlalchemy

I'm new the Alchemy so forgive me if this is a basic question. I have table classes that are reflected from an existing database and I would like to store them in a separate file. Right now I have my classes at the top of my main application:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://'+user+':'+passwd+'@'+database, echo = False)
meta_data = MetaData(bind = engine, reflect = True)

Base = declarative_base()

class Table_1(Base):
    __table__ = Table('node_lmp', meta_data, autoload=True)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Table2(Base):
    __table__ = Table('type_lmp', meta_data, autoload=True)
    def __init__(self, data, name):
        self.data = data
        self.name = name

Rest of application...
```

I'm not sure how I can export these classes to a separate module since they rely on metadata from an established connection.

I have tried experimenting with DeferredReflection to no avail. I'm a little lost on this one.

Answer (score 0):

For example lets have a directory structure like this:

```
MainDir/
   __init__.py
   main.py
   modelsDir/
      __init__.py
      meta.py
      modelA.py
```

If you want to build python program with several files you need __ init__.py -file, leave it empty. It packages other python files so that your main.py can use them, and they are callable.

In your meta.py you can but those engine, meta_data and Base variables as they are in your main file. In modelA.py you can call those metadatas like this:

```
from MainDir.modelsDir.meta import {
   engine,
   meta_data,
   Base
}
```

Importing those tables to main-file happens just like above. Look for more information about the importing stuff from here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html You can import variables(engine etc.) and classes in the same way.